# how to handle strings in prolog

Tags: prolog

i need to check if a string is available in given prolog statement

example

related('also-5','be-8').

i want to check if be is there in this statement how to do?

please give me some link to detailed tutorial on string handling in prolog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant sections in the [SWI-Prolog manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/refman/):

- Analysing and Constructing Atoms
- Representing text in strings